# Codeigniter 3 iterate multidimensional array and insert in database (controller and model)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new to CodeIgniter and poor php (sorry for my English I'm Italian :) ....).

I have a problem that I can not solve. I would like to iterate the contents of folders and subfolders and insert into databases with a table and 2 columns (folder_name 'or subfolder' and file_name). I wanted to use the **directory_map function ('./mydirectory/');** but I have serious problems in understanding how to iterate the multidimensional array and insert information on `DB MySQL` (... sorry).
Can someone help me to solve this problem by writing an example how to make the controller and the model?

Every help will be appreciated.
Thanks so much

Comment: you can start with this : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html

Comment: you need to make an attempt.. it doesn't have to be right, as long as you've shown some initiative in learning foreach loops. I'd start with using that map function and print_r'ing its response to see how you can manipulate the data... that being said, i think you'll probably need a more advanced function to pull off what you want. either way, learn foreach's and then basic db structure and inserts using CI.

Comment: thanks, I have the basics of CI, but I do not understand how to handle this type of array. I tried in different ways but without results.